# Tableview gets black while data loads from the server

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

hello I have `tableview` in which I am populating data from the `web service`. I am showing `activity indicator` first on the tableview until data comes from the server. The problem is while spinner is moving table gets black until data comes up and table moves to white color like I designed. But Before that it shows separator lines and black background for like 2 sec. How can I show complete white background with the spinner and also with no separator lines like in many apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The black background is most likely the background color of your `tableView`, because before populating the `tableView` your reusable cells don't exist in the view. If your `tableView` has a transparent background the black color is due to the color of the background of your `view`.

If you want to get rid of the separators just for the loading, I suggest creating a `tableFooterView` and removing it when populating the `tableView`.

Comment: okay so what should I do to that black color? I even set these lines  self.myTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
But its not working

Comment: Could you add some code to your question to show exactly what you're doing?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what causes the black color from your comment but you can disable separator lines as such:

```
self.tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone
```